# Flink Application throw Class Not Found Exception in Java

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a Flink Cluster with Yarn, use the flink-quickstart-java Archetype to build a demo project. After building a fat-jar with 'mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar' command, and submit the program with 'flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 ./flink-SNAPSHOT-1.0.jar', the program throw the following exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09.setDeserializer(FlinkKafkaConsumer09.java:290)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09.(FlinkKafkaConsumer09.java:216)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09.(FlinkKafkaConsumer09.java:154)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010.(FlinkKafkaConsumer010.java:128)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010.(FlinkKafkaConsumer010.java:112)
>           at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010.(FlinkKafkaConsumer010.java:79)
>           at stream.TransferKafka.main(TransferKafka.java:19)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:525)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:417)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:395)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:828)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:283)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1080)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1127)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$1.call(CliFrontend.java:1124)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1781)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1124)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 24 more

And Here is my demo:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
 final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "ip:port");
 props.setProperty("group.id", "NewFlinkTest");
 DataStreamSource < String > stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010 < > ("kafka_test", new SimpleStringSchema(), props));
 stream.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer010 < > ("kafka_test_out", new SimpleStringSchema(), props));
 try {
  env.execute("Flink Jar Test");
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

And some version information:
FLink Version: 1.4.0

Hadoop Version: 2.7.2

Kafka Version: 0.10.2.1

JDK Version: 1.8

---

Pom dependencies

Edit1:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dependencies>
   <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <!-- This dependency is required to actually execute jobs. It is currently pulled in by           flink-streaming-java, but we explicitly depend on it to safeguard against future changes. -->
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- explicitly add a standard logging framework, as Flink does not have     a hard dependency on one specific framework by default -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After some attempts, I find the code throws exception is not the same jar that I packed into my uber-jar. I think the main reason is the client server has older version of the flink-connector-kafka jar, but no matter how I set the config yaml property '**yarn.per-job-cluster.include-user-jar**', the program always throws the same exception.

---

Edit2:

After add kafka-clients:0.10.2.1 to flink_home/lib/, it works. But still don't know the reason why it doesn't read class file in uber jar.

Comment: Please add Your dependencies from `pom.xml`

Comment: Dependency information has been added @Dominik Wosiński

Answer (score 0):

First, you may verify if the missing class is in your jar file by `grep 'ByteArrayDeserializer' ./flink-SNAPSHOT-1.0.jar`.

Comment: Yes, the class file is in the jar.

Comment: That's weird, could you copy the `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients: 0.10.2.1` jar file which contains `ByteArrayDeserializer` class from maven repository to *flink-home/lib* folder to verify if it's really a missing dependency issue?

Comment: After I add the jar to lib/ , it works. But I still want to know the reason why it doesn't use the class file in the uber jar, even I change the conf  'yarn.per-job-cluster.include-user-jar'.

Comment: I think it has no relation with the conf ''yarn.per-job-cluster.include-user-jar', since this conf affects classpath of JobManager&TaskManager running on Yarn. Your exception happened within 'CliFrontend'. Anyway I haven't came up with any possible reasons, it should work fine with your settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `<scope>provided</scope>` to flink-streaming-scala, flink-clients, link-table-api-scala-bridge and flink-table-planner-blink - that solves my problem